# regular expressions: $ not allowed

Tags: regex

I was testing my regular expression skill at [this site](https://alf.nu/RegexGolf).
One of the questions was to come up with an expression that would match "fu, dofu, snafu" but not "futz, fusillade, functional, discombobulated".
I thought this an easy task and entered my answer as "fu$". To my surprise, the answer was not accepted. I then looked at the question more closely and found this phrase: "$ not allowed." Now, I'm stuck.

What should the regular expression be?

```
match      match not
fu         futz
dofu       fusillade
snafu      functional
           discombobulated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to just match word which end in `fu`, but not necessarily words that only have `fu` as a substring without also ending in `fu`.  Consider using:

```
\b\w*fu\b
```

This matches any word which ends in `fu`, possibly preceded by other word characters.

### Demo

Comment: Even just `fu\b` would be enough to solve that very task.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, if the OP only wants to _match_ your suggestion is fine; if it also wants to extract the full matching words, then it is not fine.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be

```
/fu+\b/mg
```

\b is a word boundary

Comment: Your pattern would match `fuu`, which isn't desired by the OP from what I can see.

Comment: Sorry, I entered your answer to the web site but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rules, this is the shortest:

```
u\b
```